# Text on Sign Up button is not aligned for localized sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, sign-up

Text on "Sign Up" button is not aligned horizontally for localized sites:

- [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)
- [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)
- [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)
- [Русский язык Stack Exchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/signup)

> [image: pt]

For ruSO this button looks fine before you click on "больше способов входа" ("more sign up options") link.

Comment: [It's not even aligned properly in English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmUZA.png). The "more sign up options" collides with the button on Spanish SO too.

Comment: @Cai we need to introduce [tag:collide] here for some design bugs. I could use it for a lot of my bug reports :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was eventually fixed...

> [image]